# Paying by voice - what is its transaction type

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, online-payment, payment

When I purchase something through voice virtual assistant, for example order Pizza through my Echo-Alexa - is it written in card schemes (Visa/Mastercard) as a **Card-Not-Present (CNP)** transaction or it's a transaction of different type?

Comment: My guess would be E-Commerce, as if you'd made a 1-click amazon purchase.

Comment: I am not sure, because the authorization of this transaction is different than authorize transaction through the web - it's only by voice command

Comment: And if I used a PC with voice-control software to buy something via the amazon website? Don't be fooled, an Echo *is* a personal computer - just one with an atypical interface.

Comment: Lt's compare to other interfaces: are transaction made by phone call treated by card schemes identically as transaction that are made by website and webservices?

Comment: OK, we're talking at different levels. E-Commerce and MOTO are both sub-categories of CNP.